# how to creat localStorage

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, local-storage

it's my first time use Redux,Please understand me

---

Hi, i created the simple app ,but without localStorage,in my code i mostly use ReactJs and Redux ..can somebody help me to create a localStorage for my "user" for use it in the futer ?

---

here is my github:
https://github.com/Adulik94/smbo-task.git

also codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-field-hdb4y

Comment: Redux and localStorage are not related to each other; redux is for storing state data in memory during a session, localStorage is for persisting data locally to the user across sessions. Which one are you trying to get help with?

Comment: @DanielBeck i want to have user info in local storage for checking authentication ...like if user are logged in i can logout(deleting user info),or before logged in can't redirect into user page

Answer (score 1):

you can simply write:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(value));
```

learn more about [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create localStorage by writing this line wherever you want to store your "user" data.

```
localStorage.setItem('user',user); // where user is the variable or state or whatever containing user data.
```

and you can get the data stored in localStorage by this line:

```
localStorage.getItem('user');
```

Comment: i think i need a reducer for it.....but as i write code i can't understand how to add it